# Loading a resource in a JAR file

Tags: java

I have a Java project in Netbeans. It runs fine with Maven. So I assembled it. It contains the following code to load a file that is in the JAR:

```
ClassLoader loader = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
SERVICE_URL = loader.getResource("my.wsdl");
```

This returns a URL like:

```
jar:file:/path/to/my/file/MyClass-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/my.wsdl
```

but the library that needs this parameter doesn't appear to be able to use it.

Is there any way this file can be in the JAR and be referred to from the code like this?

Comment: When you say "runs" do you mean the Java project compiles or the compiled application executes?

Comment: it executes - i think the lack of an exception is due to a crappy library that requires the above file rather than a problem with maven specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to use ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(), copy it to a temporary file, and then create a URL with File.toURI().toURL()